# Sequelize selecting id instead of foreign key

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, graphql

I have a `Book` table, a `Category` table and a join table named `BookCategories`. Here's an oversimplified structure:

```
books {
  id,
  name,
  hash // unique
}

categories {
  id,
  name
}

book_categories {
  id,
  book_hash,
  category_id
}
```

Because of the way the app works, it was decided to use the `book_hash` in the join table instead of the `book_id`.

Here are the **Sequelize** relations between the 3 tables:

```
// book
Book.hasMany(models.bookCategories, { foreignKey: 'book_hash' });

// category
Category.hasMany(models.bookCategories, { foreignKey: 'category_id' });

// bookCategories
BookCategories.belongsTo(models.book, { foreignKey: 'collection_hash' });
BookCategories.belongsTo(models.category, { foreignKey: 'category_id' });
```

I'm using Sequelize with GraphQL, so when creating the `books` field on the `CategoryType`, everything works great:

```
books: {
  type: new GraphQLList(BookType),
  args: defaultListArgs(),
  async resolve(f, args) {
    return await f.getBookCategories(args);
    // normally doesn't return, uses results to get book hashes and return books
  }
}
```

It runs the following queries:

```
SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `categories` ASC;
SELECT `id`, `book_hash`, `category_id` FROM `book_categories` AS `bookCategories` WHERE `bookCategories`.`category_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

But when doing it the other way around, requesting the bookCategories through the `BookType`, it doesn't:

```
categories: {
  type: new GraphQLList(CategoryType),
  args: defaultListArgs(),
  async resolve(f, args) {
    return await f.getBookCategories(args);
    // normally doesn't return, uses results to get category ids and return categories
  }
}
```

It runs these queries:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `hash`,  FROM `books` AS `book` WHERE `book`.`hash` = 'ft3qvqlj';
SELECT `id`, `book_hash`, `category_id` FROM `book_categories` AS `bookCategories` WHERE `bookCategories`.`book_hash` IN (93586);
```

As you can see, even though I set the foreign key to the hash on both relations, it still uses the book id to do the query. Does it have to do with the fact that `hash` is not the primary key on the `books` table?

Is there a way to fix this or do I have to redo the database structure?

Comment: If you do not declare any column as primary key sequelize will assume book id to be the one. And use it for association querying. Also you might need use version 1.7.X to do so

Comment: I did declare `id` as primary key in the books table. Why does it think I want to use `id` even though I specified the hash as being the foreign key?

Comment: Yes that the issue there must be one primary key which will be used as foreign key by other table, you must make hash as a primary key